# filtering reviews according to product django

Tags: python, django, templates, django-filter

I want my  reviews that are on that particular product to be shown only on that product not on any other . I do not know how to filter it. Recently it is showing all the reviews on every product.

My **models.py** file is:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product , on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=3000 , blank=True)
    rate = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=RATE_CHOICES)
    likes= models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.full_name
```

my product **models.py** is:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=110)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=10)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
    quantity=models.IntegerField(default=1)
    discount_price=models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    size = models.CharField(choices=SIZE_CHOICES, max_length=20)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path)
    description = RichTextField(max_length=1000)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

my **product detail views.py** is:

```
class ProductDetailSlugView(ObjectViewedMixin,DetailView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    context_object_name = "object_list"
    template_name = "product_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args ,**kwargs):
        context = super(ProductDetailSlugView , self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['reviews'] = Review.objects.all()
        # context['reviews'] = Review.objects.filter(product=self.request.product)
        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(self.request)
        context['cart'] = cart_obj
        # context['comments'] = Comment.objects.all()
        return context
```

my product_detail.html is:

```html
<!--                            {% for review in reviews %}-->when i do this with my code it show me all the product
<!--                            <h1>{{review.text}}{{review.rate}}</h1>-->
<!--                            {% endfor %}-->
                            {% for review in product.review_set.all %}
                                     {{ review.text }}
                            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to make a query separately for your reviews. You can simply loop over them using your instance of `Product` in the template. Also for some reason you have set `context_object_name = "object_list"` try this:

```
{% for review in object.review_set.all %}
    {{ review.text }}
{% endfor %}
```

Here `review_set` is simply the default `related_name` set by Django which is the related models name in lowercase with `_set` appended to it. You can chose to set the related name yourself like so if you want:

```
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='reviews', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Anyway if you insist on modifying the view you can simply do this:

```
class ProductDetailSlugView(ObjectViewedMixin,DetailView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    context_object_name = "object_list"
    template_name = "product_detail.html"
    
    def get_context_data(self, *args ,**kwargs):
        context = super(ProductDetailSlugView , self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['reviews'] = Review.objects.filter(product=self.object)
        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(self.request)
        context['cart'] = cart_obj
        # context['comments'] = Comment.objects.all()
        return context
```

And then you can use this:

```
{% for review in reviews %}
    {{ review.text }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: sir it is not working. My question is still there that the reviews are showing on every product. I want the reviews that are for specific product do not show me on other product.

Comment: @HumaQureshi please add your template `product_detail.html` to your question.

Comment: sir i do not think that the problem is in product_detail..html.  The problem is in my Product DetailSlugView in context['reviews'] = Review.objects.all() because it shows all the reviews not filtered reviews. I want the reviews which are on one product do not show me on other product. but right now it is showing all the products reviews

Comment: @HumaQureshi I have edited the answer please check. Also why do you set `context_object_name = "object_list"`? object_list does not make much sense here as a Detail View will give you only one object (here one instance of `Product`). If you remove that you will automatically have the object named as `product` in the context.

Comment: Sir still not working. Because i think there is no problem in product_detail.html. All where i fail is i can not filter the reviews according to theproduct variable because the product is using foreign key

Comment: @HumaQureshi Is this the same view (`ProductDetailSlugView`) you are talking about? You don't need to filter here as the related manager would do that for you. In this view you simply display **one** product and as long as you replace all places where you wrote the loop `{% for review in reviews %}` with the one I give you will display the reviews of the current product **only**. Does "not working" mean that you see other reviews? or does it mean you see no reviews?

Comment: yes sir this is the same view and I replace {% for review in reviews %} with the one you give me

Comment: @HumaQureshi I edited once again I feel that you might be confused with some other view / template but anyway if you see the last code block you can pass the filtered reviews that way...

Comment: sir it is still not showing me any comment

Comment: @HumaQureshi Do check that you are not mistaking this view with some other... Most likely that's the issue here.

Comment: sir it worked .THANK YOU SO MUCH  the problem was in context['reviews'] = Review.objects.all()